# How to use chemfig for chemical reaction with skeletal forms

Tags: formatting, chemfig

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filcenter\normalfont\bfseries}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
{0pt}
{}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-24pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.75} 

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\schemestart
\chemfig{C(-[:0]H)(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}\+\chemfig{Cl_2}
\arrow
\chemfig{C(-[:0]Cl)(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}\+\chemfig{H(-[:0]Cl)
\schemestop
\end{center}

\end
```

I wanted to produce this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had a syntax error with a final `}` bracket missing on the last compound.  Apart from that to put a label on an arrow use the general form

```
\arrow{->[up][down]}
```

To colour atoms, use `{\color{red}H}`. However, in a number of situations, such as ends of bonds, you need to write `{}|{\color{red}H}` instead.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \schemestart
  \chemfig{C(-[:0]{}|{\color{red}H})(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}
    \+\chemfig{{}|{\color{blue}Cl_2}}
  \arrow{->[\( h\nu \)][]}
  \chemfig{C(-[:0]{}|{\color{blue}Cl})(-[:90]H)(-[:180]H)(-[:270]H)}
    \+\chemfig{{\color{red}H}(-[:0]{}|{\color{blue}Cl})}
  \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The named colours come from the `xcolor` package, so as Manuel points out you could use `magenta` instead of `red` and `cyan` instead of `blue`.

Note: I originally wrote the material over the arrow as `h\chemnu`, but as cgneider points out that is most certainly not correct.

Comment: Use `magenta` and `cyan` and it's perfect.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, those are closer to the poster's image colours.  I'll leave it up to the the poster to adjust that.

Comment: I'm not sure the `\chemnu` is the right choice here. It's purpose is to provide an upright nu (which it gives when `upreek` is loaded for example). Here nu is a normal variable (frequency of light) and h is Planck's constant so IMHO it should be `$h\nu$`

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks, I have added such a comment to the answer.  The poster does not load `upgreek` in the given code.

Comment: @AndrewSwann How `\chemnu` looks is not fixed (see http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2105#2107 for an example in German). However, only in the default setting when the user loads no package for upright Greek letters it maps to `\nu`. Details are explained in [`chemgreek`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemgreek)'s and [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros)' manuals

Comment: @cgnieder OK.  Answer, changed accordingly.

Comment: @Andrew Swann thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @Manuel thank you for emphasizing the correct color.